# Get Facebook campaign name in the application

Tags: facebook, mobile, installation, tracking, ads

I use both AppsFlyer and Facebook app install for campaigns, and in AppsFlyer I can use a delegate to get the campaign name and ad name from inside the app. In IOS I mean.
Is there a way to get the campaign/ad name of Facebook app install from inside the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that with [AppsFlyer's](http://www.appsflyer.com/) delegate. See this [link](http://support.appsflyer.com/entries/69796693-Accessing-AppsFlyer-Attribution-Conversion-Data-from-the-SDK-Deferred-Deep-linking-) for the structure of the delegate data.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. I already fixed the issue with AppsFlyer, I marked you r answer as it is the right one :)